# How to prevent a duplicated mesh getting same material

Tags: edit-mode

I have created a duplicate mesh using shift D.
I can move the duplicate mesh and also modify the duplicate mesh without affecting the original HOWEVER when I apply a material to one of the meshes the material is applied to both. Can't work out how to prevent this happening. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: You need to give a new material to the copy, it seems unavoidable

Comment: @moonboots  Thanks that is really weird. So I applied a material to the original and it also was applied to the copy, then I removed the material from the copy and gave it a new material. THAT is a real TRAP IMHO.

Comment: I guess this is because by default it makes more sense to keep the same material than to give zero material or to give a brand new material to the copy

Comment: @moonboots. I agree. I also have now noted if a material is applied to the original (or copy) and then removed then the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: I can't reproduce. If the material is shared  by the objects, then naturally, _modifications_ to the material will affect both. If I Shift D before assigning materials, then the material is applied only to the selected dupe.

Comment: I understood the question as @RobinBetts did, it reads like first you duplicate the object, then you give it a material. In this case the material wouldbe  on one object, not both. But if this happens in your Blender, I cannot reproduce it. If you simply mean you duplicate an object already with material, and the new object has the same - yes, of course it works like that by default. Duplicating an object first of all means getting an exact copy of the original object. How should the Duplicate tool know if you want to change something afterwards and what? Modify the mesh? Change the material?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann. NO I have NOT duplicated a mesh which already has a material applied. I have uploaded a very simple blender mesh file (link below). It is a cube which I duplicated (shift D) then dragged it away from the original. Then I select the original and apply RED colored material and it 'paints BOTH meshes. <img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=YjsS1ygX" />

Comment: Sorry I didn't cut ad copy the url correctlly for the example. Here it is  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bp0kv2MS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bp0kv2MS/)   HEY I now notice what the cause is. The original cube already has a material applied to it. I was using the cube which is displayed when Blender starts up. When I CREATE a new cube mesh there is NO material. That is annoying. I must remember NEVER to use the cube mesh which is there when you start up Blender Grrrrr!

Comment: Can't edit my last post as more than 5 minutes old. The problem I had seems can be reproduced by duplicating the mesh cube which displays on Blender startup which already has a material applied even though it is the same neutral color as with mesh ADDed. Why  then can't the 'default' mesh cube which gets displayed on Blender startup NOT have a mesh attached?  Grrrrr!

Comment: @JohnArnold You can edit the startup file... just open a new scene, delete the material from the cube, then go into the _File_ menu, _Defaults_ > _Save Startup File_.

Comment: @GordonBrickmann  That Gordon that's what I did yesterday although it may never bother me again now that I know the cause. I am still wondering what benefit there is in having the 'default' cube come with a material applied with no color etc.

Comment: @JohnArnold Because it has been like this for ages and nobody bothered to change it? Because most people who model things might in the end want to put some material on it for rendering anyway? And if you argue about some people not wanting this by default... why stop complaining about the material? The default scene has a cube, a camera and a point light. What if I don't need any of this, because I just model raw meshes, starting with a plane, no camera needed because I export them for Unity? And here's the thing I mentioned before: *you can change the startup file if you don't like it.*

Comment: ...and by the way, it's not "with no color", it's a light gray, almost white, at a value of 0.8, and it just so happens that they made the look of an object without any material the same, or else (like if they chose pure black for example) it would not show very much detail in the viewport if you decided to model without material. Also if you think it would have made more sense if a default material had "a color", which one would be "correct"? Blue? Pink? Yellow? What's wrong with a neutral light grey? Giving it a material by default is a starting point, like adding a cube in the first place.

Comment: Point taken. I had previouslyremoved the light and camera and saved as default startup (as I don't use them) but did NOT realise there was a 'light gray' material already applied as looking at how it is represented on my monitor it doesn't look any different with no material.  This would never have been a problem if I had realised there was a material attached BEFORE I created my multi-sided mesh by collapsing the default cube to one vertex and then creating the mesh using extrude and how can there be a material attached to a mesh with only one vertex I wonder (I am still learning heaps).

Comment: When all is 'done and dusted' its only 'horses for courses'. It is an example I guess and in many ways it should include a material although a material which is visually different from no material IMHO would be better especially as the user would want to change the material color anyway. It's just my mind and assumption.

Comment: @JohnArnold Well, I often heard people having problems understanding why duplicating an object not automatically makes the material on the new object independent from the first, but never complaining about there being a material in the first place. But anyway, actually there is a difference between default or no material if you look at it in _Rendered_ view with a light source - the _Principled BSDF_ has a semi-rough glossiness, whereas no material is completely dull like if you would put a _Diffuse BSDF_ on it (I think this was the default material before the _Principled BSDF_ existed).

Comment: @JohnArnold And how a material can be attached to a mesh with only a single vertex is quite easy: it is *not attached* to the mesh. You misunderstand the concept of an object and a mesh. An object is a container, and the object type determines what it contains. For example, a _Curve_ object cannot hold mesh data, while a _Mesh_ object cannot contain curve data. A mesh object can hold mesh data, but there most not be any data present. So you could even delete all vertices in _Edit Mode_, but the object would still be there.

Comment: @JohnArnold It would have its origin point that can be moved, it can keep modifiers that will manipulate a mesh if there was any, and it can hold materials in its material slots. The first slot is always the base material. This will be put on all parts of the mesh that are not assigned with a different material. Of course it will only show up if there are faces, because single points or edges without faces are not visible in render.

Comment: @JohnArnold The advantage of material slots by the way is, you can add slots without having any materials in them, and assign those to faces. Which means, you can determine parts of the mesh where you know you want to have different materials than the base material, without having to decide immediately in the beginning of the modelling process what these materials should be. Later you can create all necessary materials and use them in the according slots.

Comment: @JohnArnold One thing I completely forgot to tell you, you can change the startup file to one with a default cube without material... or in the _Preferences_ you could go to _Editing > Duplicate Data_ and check _Material_. If you do that, duplicating an object will give the new object a new material which is not the same as the original. Problem with this setting is, it will then always do that. Which means, if you place 10 objects in your scene by duplicating them and afterwards you decide to change the color, each object has to be changed individually (or you use Ctrl+L to link materials).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Gordon.  I decided to give the cube a distinct easily seen color (NOT 0.8 0.8 0.8) to remind me that it already has a material. IMHO not sure why that color (above) was chosen  regardless of the advantages or not of having a material on the default cube as who would ever not change remove it or change it anyway.